# MySQL sum of values from different tables with different number of columns

Tags: mysql, select, union

I'm basing on this question: [mySQL sum of two values in 2 different tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36828210/mysql-sum-of-two-values-in-2-different-tables)

In my case, the tables does look like this:

```
table_1
reference    quantity   name
TS00001      235        AAA
TS00002      400        BBB
TS00003      850        CCC
...

table_2
reference    quantity
TS00001      670
TS00002      210
TS00003      150
...
```

I'd like to get sum of `quantity` from both tables for given `reference`, but at the same time I'd like to get the `name` for the `reference` from `table_1`.

The provided answer:

```
SELECT reference, SUM(quantity) AS total_quantity
FROM (
  SELECT reference, quantity
  FROM table_1

  UNION ALL

  SELECT reference, quantity
  FROM table_2) AS t
GROUP BY reference
```

does the trick, if I want to simply get sum of values. I tried to make modification like this to get the name as well:

```
SELECT reference, name, SUM(quantity) AS total_quantity
FROM (
  SELECT reference, name, quantity
  FROM table_1

  UNION ALL

  SELECT reference, quantity
  FROM table_2) AS t
GROUP BY reference
```

But it does not work, it does return `The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns`.

Expected result should look like this:

```
reference    total_quantity   name
TS00001      905              AAA
TS00002      610              BBB
TS00003      1000             CCC
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While writing the question I found solution. We need to artificially input the missing column to the table that does not have it to match the numbers of columns from both tables.

Since we don't want to give there any additional data, the trick is to add `NULL as name` in the table that does not have column `name`.

```
SELECT reference, MAX(name) AS final_name, SUM(quantity) AS total_quantity
FROM (
  SELECT reference, name, quantity
  FROM table_1

  UNION ALL

  SELECT reference, NULL as name, quantity
  FROM table_2) AS t
GROUP BY reference
```

This does return the expected output without errors.

Edit: Changed `MAX(name) AS final_name` according to @ysth comment.

Comment: this could sometimes return NULL as the name for references that are in both tables; make it `SELECT reference, GREATEST(name), SUM(quantity)` instead.  This will also allow your select to work in only_full_group_by mode, which is the default on newer mysql versions.

Comment: @ysth Thank You for the upgrade! How this can "sometimes" return NULL? Is it kinda-random, or it does require specific conditions to happen?

Comment: Wait, it does not work like that, it does return `Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'GREATEST'` - did I missunderstood something?

Comment: when you group by reference, and select things that don't come from all rows for the reference, you will get the value from an arbitrary one of the rows being grouped (or an error in only_full_group_by mode, which makes mysql behave according to the SQL standard and like most other databases).   see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: oops, sorry, I meant MAX(), not GREATEST()

Comment: Oh, now it make sense, I added there an alias in this case - does work in my project as well, so it should be fine. THX again for upgrade!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different approach using `JOIN` and instead of `SUM()`, you simply just add the value:

```
SELECT table_1.reference, 
       table_1.name AS final_name, 
       table_1.quantity + table_2.quantity AS total_quantity
FROM   table_1 
JOIN   table_2 
ON     table_1.reference=table_2.reference;
```

A fiddle for demo : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9541k7FCfz5JvqggsoJ12S/2